# Magento 2 - Add Custom Attribute to Product Collection without Flat Catalog EAV?

Tags: magento2, product, collection, sql

I have the below collection:

```
$this->_collection->getSelect()
                  ->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('price_index.min_price / IF(e.unit_of_sale = NULL, 1, e.unit_of_sale) DESC'));
```

This is used for sorting by each price on the frontend and worked perfectly while **product flat catalog** was enabled. Now however with product flat catalog disabled the following error is shown:

```
Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.unit_of_sale' in 'order clause'
```

I'm guessing i need to add the attribute so it can be used for the ORDER clause. I have tried the below however with no luck:

1. `->addAttributeToSelect('unit_of_sale')`
2. `->addFieldToSelect('unit_of_sale')`

Using `->addAttributeToFilter('unit_of_sale')` gets rid of the error and so have just created a false filter `->addAttributeToFilter('unit_of_sale', array('neq' => '-1'))` so that I can use the attribute for the order but would rather know how to add the attribute for order clause.

How can i add a custom attribute to a collection while flat catalog is disabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the **catalog_product_entity_varchar** table as a second paramater to the addAttributeToSelect method call seemed to fix my issue:

```
->addAttributeToSelect('unit_of_sale', 'catalog_product_entity_varchar')
```

Comment: worked. It seems we have to pass the required table name based on the attribute type as the 2nd parametre

Answer (score 0):

```
            $collection = $productCollection->create()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured', array('eq' => 1))
                    ->load();
```

Comment: Try to add some description to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter is join type, you can use 'left' to get extra field into the collection.
eg. ->addAttributeToSelect(['price','special_price'],'left');